# Any way to convert an array of strings to an array of characters?

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

In short, I have an array of words such as `{apple, banana, cat}`
and I'm looking to see if I can convert that into `{a, p, p, l, e, b, a, ....}`
I'm not sure if it's even possible.

My initial stupid attempt:

```
for(String s: lelWords)
{
    lelChars.add(s.toCharArray());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] strArray = {"apple", "banana", "cat"};
//combine all words to one string
String combStr = new String();
for(String string: strArray)
    combStr += string;

char[] charArray = combStr.toCharArray();
//checking
System.out.println(charArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Should be pretty simple

```
int numChars = 0;

//determine the total number of characters
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) 
  numChars += strings[i].length();
int idx = 0;

//declare our final array of characters
char[] chars = new char[numChars];

//populate our new array
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < strings[i].length; j++) {
    chars[idx] = strings[i].charAt(j);
    idx++;
  }
}
```